# codeigniter single result without foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am using codeigniter to get a single result from the db, like this:

```
$user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1");
```

I am then getting the returned object and looping trough it, this way:

```
foreach ($user->result() as $row) { ... }
```

As you can imagine, there is not point in using the loop, since there is only one result. Is there a way to get users parameters without looping? Something among this line:

```
echo $user['name'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")->row();
```

for having it as an object ( `echo $user->name;`)

```
$user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")->row_array();
```

for having is as an array ( `echo $user['name'];` );

```
$user = $this->db->limit(1)->get('users')->row(); //or ->row_array();
```

using AR;

```
$row = $user->first_row();
```

to get the first row out of a result set ($this->db->result()), as an object (default);

```
$row = $user->first_row('array');
```

to get the first row out of a result set, as an array;

```
$row = $user->row_array(1);
```

to return a specific row (first, in this case. Just pass the `<N>` of the row). Works also for `$user->row(1);`

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
$user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")->row_array();
```

More details here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
    //in the model
    $query = $this->db->query("your query");

$row = $query->row();

    if (isset($row))
return $row;
}else{
return false;
}
```

then echo your results like this

```
echo $row->username;
```

if you want to pass it to a view

```
//in the controller

$this->load->model('somemodel');
        $hm=$this->somemodel->somemethod();
        $data['query']=$hm;
    $this->load->view('path/to/view',$data);
```

Then echo the same way

```
echo $row->username;
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose for example your model function is like this.......

```
 public function get_users()
 {

  $query = "Select * from users limit 1";

  $res=$this->db->query($query);

    if($res->num_rows()>0){
        return $res->result("array");
    }
    return array();
 }
```

Suppose you are calling this model in your controller function like this

```
    $users =  $this->model_file->get_users();
```

then you can echo like this `echo $users[0]['user_name'];`

Comment: I am not facing any problems with that kind of syntax. I used it for all queries through out my application.

Comment: I never saw it mentioned; I just see this: `You can also pass a string to result() which represents a class to instantiate for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)`

Comment: Don't worry I don't have that basic knowledge in PHP & CI. Any way leave it like that but  it's not wrong that i can say ........